# php file renaming loop

Tags: php, loops, renaming

I run a ecommerce site, and I have tons of product images.
The naming rules are simple: `productid-picnumber`.

But sometimes theres gaps betweeen the picnumbers.

Example for the pictures for product id 4519:

```
4519-0.jpg
4519-3.jpg
4519-4.jpg
4519-5.jpg
4519-8.jpg
```

I'm trying to write an algorithm to rename the pictures. The pictures from this product should be renamed like this:

```
4519-0.jpg
4519-1.jpg
4519-2.jpg
4519-3.jpg
4519-4.jpg
```

In order. 0 must always be 0, as it's the main product image. -0 is always there.
Let's say `$ids` is an array containing all my product ids.

Is looping through the product ids and using `file_exists()` the best way?

Comment: I mean, is there a fundamental reason that the `-#` needs to be sequential?

Comment: the reason is the function for printing my product images goes like this. it loops, and checks if -1 exists, if it does, it prints it, and then it checks -2 and prints, and so on

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562298/php-how-to-search-a-file-using-wildcards

Comment: thank you, i didnt know glob could do wildcards. i rather changed my file read function

Comment: My own preference would be to ignore the blanks in the sequence, unless I just have to have the numbers in order for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly suggest you that you get all filenames from a directory listing first, and then run the renaming "dry" (map oldname -> new name for the files to change) and then output if the actual result of the operation is the expected result.

This will not only save you much `file_exists` checks but also keeps things more safely.

Additionally you can think of using some standard file-system utilities which can rename/renumber files quite quickly. Check your OS documentation.