# How to get a file extension from path with any extension? Solved

Tags: php, html, file, path

Solved! "../pictures/uploads/profile" I changed to "./pictures/uploads/profile". My mistake, sorry! And I used answer from @Kunal Raut

I want to get extension of file in PHP from path. I have this code:

```
$fileName = "../pictures/uploads/profile".$id.".*";
$ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$sourceImg = "../pictures/uploads/profile".$id.".".$ext."?".mt_rand();
```

I have folder with pictures. They can be in png or jpg or jpeg. And php file is in another folder. So how do that?

Comment: It will works for one file, not for a set of files. You are using .* like if you was getting all files with name "profile5.anything"

Comment: What is the value of `$id` here?

Comment: It's working perfectly. It's returns `*` as extension.

Comment: @KunalRaut It's id of user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: How to search a file using wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562298/php-how-to-search-a-file-using-wildcards)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get all the extensions in the directory by using the function `scandir()` as

```
$fileName = scandir("../pictures/uploads/");
$ext = "";
foreach($fileName as $files) {
if($files !== '.' && $files !== '..') {
$ext = pathinfo($files, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 }
}
 echo $ext .'<br>';
```

Usually *scandir()* returns the first two values in the array as `.` and `..` and by if condition mentioned in the answer you can delete these unwanted values and get the answer in the pure form.

**Note :** `scandir()` returns the values in the form of array.

i got it working see below

[image]

Comment: i have posted a working example image for you check it out and also do check my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

$fileName = "../pictures/uploads/profile".$id.".*"; // <---- this is not a file,put a file name
$ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Try this:

```
$files = scandir("../pictures/uploads/");
foreach ($files as $fileName) {
   $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
}
```

Comment: I have folder with pictures. They can be in png or jpg or jpeg. And php file is in another folder. So how do that?

Comment: You can read all the files in the folder. Ie: you can use scandir function. Ir returns an array with all files, then you can make a foreach. I have edit my answer.

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe now it's easier to understand

Comment: @Curlas  but it will return dots `.` in the first two array.

Comment: @Curlas But how $fileName must look then? 'cause id doesn't give extension

Answer (score 0):

Just use the DirectoryIterator class.

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../pictures/uploads') as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

    if (stripos($fileInfo->getFilename(), 'profile' . $id) !== false) {
        var_dump($fileInfo->getExtension());
    }
}
```

The [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getextension.php) class is available since PHP 5.3.6.

A more detailed example could be a DirectoryIterator instance used by a FilterIterator instance to just output the desired files. Th given example requires a minimum of PHP 7.4. If you 're using a PHP version smaller than 7.4 remove the type hints for the class properties.

```
class MyFileFilter extends FilterIterator
{
    protected string $filename;
    public function __construct(Iterator $iterator, $filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept(): bool
    {
        $info = $this->getInnerIterator();
        return stripos($info->getFilename(), $this->filename) !== false;
    }
}
```

The [FilterIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) class is available since PHP 5.1. The above shown extension takes an Iterator and searches for a given filename and returns the SplFileInfo object, if the filename matches.

How to use it:

```
$directory = new DirectoryIterator('../pictures/uploads');
$filename = 'picture' . $id;
$filter = new MyFileFilter($directory, $filename);

foreach ($filter as $file) {
    var_dump($file->getExtension());
}
```

The foreach loop is basically the filter, that only returns files, that match the given filename. Every returned file is a SplFileInfo instance. With this you can use the SplFileInfo::getExtension() method to get the file extension.

Last but not least comes the [GlobIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php) class which is available since PHP 5.3. It 's the easiest way to iteratate over a given path with placeholders.

```
$filesystem = new GlobIterator('../pictures/uploads/profile' . $id . '.*');
foreach ($filesystem as $file) {
    var_dump($file->getExtension());
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe now it's easier to understand

Comment: Well, if I understand your changes, you are searching for all files with a given filename in a specific path to get the file extension. That 's exactly what my given code examples do.

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)" on line with "protected string"

Comment: Well, that sounds like a PHP version < 7.4. What php version are you running? Try `echo PHP_VERSION;`.

Comment: It's 7.2.30 version

Comment: I 've edited my answer and gave you an example for the GlobIterator class, which is available since PHP 5.3. This should work.

Comment: Still don't get extension

Comment: What do you get instead? What did you try from the above? Are you using the right directory? Does a filename with the given `$id` even exist in the directory? Show me some code.

Comment: Well ... you should not just copy code from stack overflow! Try to understand, what the code does and transfer that to your application. The line `$ext = var_dump($file->getExtension);` can not work! Change it into `$ext = $file->getExtension();`.

Comment: I changed that but still can't got extension

Comment: Solved! "../pictures/uploads/profile" I changed to  "./pictures/uploads/profile". My mistake, sorry! And I used answer from @Kunal Raut